# Add Firestore data to DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatables, google-cloud-firestore

I try to load data to my dataTable from my Firestore database but it doeasn't work. Is there any other way to push data from firestore to array?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pageName').html('Dashboard');
  $('#pageName-li').html('Dashboard');

  var dataSet = [];
  x = 1

  let db = firebase.firestore();

  db.collection("warehouses").where("useremail", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.email).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      dataSet[x][1] = doc.data().name;
      dataSet[x][2] = doc.data().useremail;
      dataSet[x][3] = doc.data().address;
      x++
    });
  });

  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { title: "Name" },
      { title: "Address" },
      { title: "User email" }
    ]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. You can best see how this affects your program with some `console.log` statements:

```
console.log("Before running query");
db.collection("warehouses").where("useremail","==",firebase.auth().currentUser.email).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
   console.log("Got data");
});
console.log("After running query");
```

When you run this code you get the following output:

> Before running query
>
> After running query
>
> Got data

This is probably not the order that you expected the output in. But it completely explains why your code doesn't work: by the time you call `$('#example').DataTable( { data: dataSet, ...` the data hasn't been loaded yet.

---

Since data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, any code that needs access to the data myst be inside the `then` callback, or be called from there.

So the simplest fix is to populate the data table from within the callback:

```
db.collection("warehouses").where("useremail","==",firebase.auth().currentUser.email).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

            dataSet[x][1] = doc.data().name;
            dataSet[x][2] = doc.data().useremail;
            dataSet[x][3] = doc.data().address;
            x++
    });
    $('#example').DataTable( {
                    data: dataSet,
                    columns: [
                            { title: "Name" },
                            { title: "Address" },
                            { title: "User email" }
                    ]
            });
});
```

Comment: If there is a new record added to the table in Firestore, will this method fetch all the records from the table or just the new one and append it to the datatable?

Comment: It'll add all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Frank
Here is the working code.
(it doesn't work without button so I added one)

```
<button type="button"  id="warehousesGetDataBTN">Get Warehouses</button>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>

<script>

function getDatainTable() {

    let db = firebase.firestore();
    var dataSet = new Array();
    var i=1;

   db.collection("warehouses").where("useremail","==",firebase.auth().currentUser.email).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

                    dataSet.push([doc.data().name, doc.data().useremail]);
                    i=i+1;

});


    $('#example').DataTable( {
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                    { title: "Name" },
                    { title: "Email" }
            ]
    } );
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $( '#warehousesGetDataBTN' ).click(function(){getDatainTable()});

});
</script>
```